# google drive sdk upload file

Tags: api, sdk, google-drive-api

I tried to upload file, but then file is called "untitle".

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
string UploadURI = String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media&access_token={0}", accessToken);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(UploadURI);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    }
string status = (((HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()).StatusDescription);
if (status.ToLower() == "created" || status.ToLower()=="ok")
    {
        Uploaded = true;
    }
```

And how can I upload a file into a specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both the "untitle" and "parent folder" questions is the same. Meta Data. When you POST you should provide a meta data object containing a title:"title" and parents: [{id:"parent_id"}]